# Improve lighthouse performance score

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

I am hosting an `Ionic-React` web app via `firebase-hosting` here:

https://drakapoor-65d6d.web.app/

I ran a lighthouse audit on the page via chrome dev-tools and got a very poor performance rating...

I am not able to understand which part of the code is causing the score to fall.

I've commented on all the routes and components for this demo, even removed the fonts, if you try to run the Lighthouse via chrome dev tools and go to "View Original Trace", It'll show the detailed analysis of the website, Below is the result that came out:

[image: Performance]

Now, if you see around 4 seconds are lost trying to load a specific chunk "https://drakapoor-65d6d.web.app/static/js/6.53bd499b.chunk.js", I have no idea what's in it, I've commended the entire project and deployed. How can I get rid of this? what is going on, I am clueless to even proceed in any direction...

LightHouse score: here if you see the largest contentful paint and speed index are very poor, what Is causing this? I'm barely even doing anything..

please let me know if I can provide anything that'll help you help me, thanks.
[image: LightHouse Performance Score]

Comment: That's basically saying your internet is slow? However,  I ran a check to [your site](https://drakapoor-65d6d.web.app/home), and got 99 score on lighthouse.

Comment: really? lighthouse PERFORMANCE score of 99? won't score take into account the network speed? also I'm on 50 Mbps speed

Comment: I believe it would take into account. Notice those 8 blank white frames in your screenshot, I believe that was when you were still fetching for resources and your browser was too slow to do it, and lighthouse thinks the file is too big, and the fact that I got 99 on my side, and this is the first time I've noticed this too. I might be wrong, but try to run it on an incognito browser (to avoid addons you have) with better internet speed.

Comment: I re ran it on incognito, and score is around 50, the detailed performance still says 4 seconds lost loading that chunk, I don't understand what that chunk even is :(

Comment: and if network speed affects the score, if I try to do this on 2g any website will have a low score right, this makes me wanna believe that network speed shouldn't affect the score, the test itself should manipulate speed for measuring performance..

Comment: `main.chunk` is your app code, and `[number].chunk` is the vendor code, if you're using CRA for that at least.

Comment: Actually, as I said that I might be wrong, but looks like I am right. FCP, as per [Google insight doc](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#crux), is a user-centric metric for measuring perceived load speed, which means how quickly a page can load and render all of its visual elements to the screen. So yes, internet speed and hardware do take into account here.

Comment: And FCP time is measured when the page starts loading. So, that's why tutorials out there are suggesting to CDNize your resources to improve FCP. As per your query, if you run it on a 2g, then YES, you will have even lower score.

Comment: Sometimes switching the audit setting device from mobile to desktop or vice versa will lower or raise the score.

Comment: There are two things at play here, first OP, I would guess you have Lighthouse set to "applied throttling" (by unchecking "Simulated Throttling" on the top left of the Lighthouse Tab). This is always less forgiving than simulated throttling. Secondly I would guess you are on a device that is either not very powerful or has a lot of background processes running. You see Lighthouse applies a 4x CPU slowdown and all of your speed problems are related to CPU processing time. Have you tried Page Speed Insights instead as the performance will be easier to compare there.

Comment: @TimothyChen you will always get a higher score on Desktop as the connection and CPU are not throttled. Mobile scores are always lower as they simulate a slower device running on fast 3G.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie hmmm maybe if you were standing right next to a cell tower...

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR; Bad lighthouse score can be caused by your network, hardware or any other 3rd party addons.

Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) is the metric of **FCP + N seconds** to the first [image or text block](https://web.dev/lcp/#what-elements-are-considered)

First Contentful Paint (FCP) is an important, user-centric metric for measuring perceived load speed because it **marks the first point in the page load timeline where the user can see anything on the screen** - a fast FCP helps reassure the user that something is happening.

And also, quoting from [Web Dev #In the Field](https://web.dev/user-centric-performance-metrics/#in-the-field);

> The performance of a site can vary dramatically based on a user's
> device capabilities and their network conditions. It can also vary
> based on whether (or how) a user is interacting with the page.

Your First Contentful Paint (FCP) which has 7.3s is considered Poor since it's over 3s. FCP is measured the first time when audit starts.

These are the classifications on the metrics (Based on [Developer Insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#crux));

```
        Good            Needs Improvement       Poor
FCP     [0, 1000ms]     (1000ms, 3000ms]        over 3000ms
FID     [0, 100ms]      (100ms, 300ms]          over 300ms
LCP     [0, 2500ms]     (2500ms, 4000ms]        over 4000ms
CLS     [0, 0.1]        (0.1, 0.25]             over 0.25
```

More details for each metric above can be found here;

- FCP - [First Contentful Paint](https://web.dev/fcp/)
- FID - [First Input Delay](https://web.dev/fid/)
- LCP - [Largest Contentful Paint](https://web.dev/lcp/)
- CLS- [Cumulative Layout Shift](https://web.dev/cls/)

As per [Performance Scoring](https://web.dev/performance-scoring/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools#fluctuations). Your score might also fluctuate based on;

- A/B tests or changes in ads being served
- Internet traffic routing changes
- Testing on different devices, such as a high-performance desktop and a low-performance laptop
- Browser extensions that inject JavaScript and add/modify network requests
- Antivirus software

In order to improve your page performance, consider the following practices;

1. Serve static assets with cache policy and CDNize them
2. Consider code-splitting, and lazy loading components, when possible
3. Minify CSS and JS. And resize image + compress with lossless compression if possible
4. Use `preload` in your links for assets that eventually will be loaded the first time when your page loads.
5. Minimize third party usage
6. Consider using passive listener for touch and wheel event listeners. Read more about it [here](https://web.dev/uses-passive-event-listeners/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools)

And there are more to it which you can also find at [Lighthouse Audit Documentation](https://web.dev/learn/#lighthouse)

Last but not least, if you have published your site - you can also have Lighthouse to audit your site at [here](https://web.dev/measure/). Which all tests are run using a simulated mobile device, throttled to a fast 3G network and 4x CPU slowdown.

[image: Site audit]